# CSS subnav menu text color change

Tags: css

[theShuttersmith.com](http://theshuttersmith.com) is my website. This site is based on a template designed by squarespace. I've managed to change the background color of the submenu box, but can't for the life of me figure out how to change the text color. I can't seem to find the snippet of css that I need to customize. I would simply like to change it to #fafafa.  Any help is appreciated. I can't post the code... because I can't figure out which piece of code to change.  If you visit the site, hover over the navigation item "Domestic Friends"... the resulting subnav menu is what I'm speaking of. Thank you!!!

Comment: Use a developer tool like f.e. Firebug, and find out yourself where the formatting is coming from …

Comment: This link will help : http://answers.squarespace.com/questions/8286/hi-in-frontrow-how-to-change-subnav-menu-texts-color-with-css

Comment: This answer may also help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16644210/css-drop-down-sub-menu-color

Answer (score 1):

To change the color of the dropdown text use:

```
.collection-type-gallery #topNav nav .folder ul li a, .collection-type-gallery #topNav nav .folder ul li a:visited {
    color: rgba(18, 18, 18, 0.7); /* CURRENT COLOR */
    color: red; /* ADDED THIS */
}
```

Also see:

```
.collection-type-gallery #topNav .main-nav a, .collection-type-gallery #topNav .secondary-nav a, .collection-type-gallery #topNav .main-nav a:visited, .collection-type-gallery #topNav .secondary-nav a:visited {
    color: #aaaaaa; /* CURRENT COLOR */
    color: red; /* ADDED THIS */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Line 4903 - 4906:

```
.collection-type-gallery #topNav nav .folder ul li a,
.collection-type-gallery #topNav nav .folder ul li a:visited {
    color: rgba(18, 18, 18, 0.7); /*delete*/
    color: #fafafa; /*add*/
}
```